# Merging array and table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with all the `ids` in an array like format and another table that matches the `ids` with the `names`. I'm required to write a query that creates creates a new table with 2 columns : `ids` (which is an array of ids) and `names` (an array with the corresponding names of the ids).

**INPUT TABLES :**

main

```
ids
---------
i1 | i2
i2 | i3
i3
```

agents

```
ids    names
--------------
i1     agent1
i2     agent2
i3     agent3
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
ids        names
----------------------------
(i1, i2)   (agent1, agent2)
(i2, i3)   (agent2, agent3)
(i3)       (agent3)
```

Output can also be in this format : `i1 | i2` for all the elements, that would be fine as well, not absolutely necessary that they should be converted to arrays as I've done below.

I managed to convert the `|` separated `ids` column to arrays, but couldn't progress after that.

```
string_to_array(substr(translate(translate(
  main.ids, '|', ','), ' ', ''), 1, length(main.ids) - 3), ',') 
  AS ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `unnest` function to expand the array into rows, then join with the other table and finally use `array_agg` to aggregate rows into single value:

```sql
SELECT 
'( ' || main.ids || ' )' AS ids,
'( ' || array_to_string(
  (SELECT array_agg(agents.names) 
    FROM unnest(
      string_to_array( replace(main.ids,' ',''), '|')
    ) as tmp(temp_main_ids) 
    LEFT JOIN agents ON tmp.temp_main_ids = agents.ids
  ),' | ') 
|| ' )' AS names
FROM main
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. Can you add the table name with the parameters, like use`main_ids` and `agent_ids` for these columns. This was like a sample example I created and I'm finding it hard to replace this.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow you - but I prefixed the columns with their respective table name.